# Enable/Disable Ribbon Controls Independently

Tags: excel, ribbon, vba

I've been searching many times for a solution to this and the closest solution is Ron de Bruin [example](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win013.htm) but it does not cover what I need.

I am trying to do is essentially 2 things

Example: I have 4 buttons.

Button1 on Group1 and tab1

Button2 on Group1 and tab1

Button3 on Group2 and tab2

Button4 on Group2 and tab2

1. When the ribbon control "Button1" is clicked it will run some code and  disable the "Button1" at the end.
2. When the ribbon control "Button2" is clicked it will run some code and the check the "Button3" and "button4" and set the opposite properties.

If button3 was true, it becomes false.

If button4 was false, it becomes true.

Can you provide some guidance to solve this

Comment: Can you explain more? The same ribbon is clicked the first time, and then a second time? what do you mean by "on the same tab and same group"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, all buttons have `GetEnabled` events, so when ribbon activates/updates - event fired! (simple).

Callback function to this event looks like this:

```
Sub Button_GetEnabled(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef enabled)
'(enabled = true to enable)
    enabled = EnableButtons
End Sub
```

So lets start! In your module with callbacks functions you need a global (global to callbacks) boolean smth like `EnableButtons`.

And when ribbon loads this code example fires setting flag to `True`:

```
Private Sub OnRib_Load(ribbonUI As IRibbonUI)
    Set MyRibbonUI = ribbonUI
    EnableButtons = True
End Sub
```

And on each button you need callback for `GetEnabled` event described above.

After that - all buttons are enabled! So what we can make here? Lets look on OnAction callback to your desired button:

```
Sub Button_Click(control As IRibbonControl)
     EnableButtons = False
     MyRibbonUI.Invalidate
     'do some stuff - buttons disabled
     EnableButtons = True
     MyRibbonUI.Invalidate
End Sub
```

So `Invalidate` method "updates" all controls. You can try to `InvalidateControl` desired control (which is a more preferable way, than `Invalidate`, due to performance), but I think that more elegant way is to place callbacks and events only on buttons you want!

So, finally, you need reference to ribbon, boolean flag, and `_GetEnabled` events.

[More here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869817.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Explantion provided by [Commonsense](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6634373/commonsense) help me to build that final solution for the revised question asked. Thanks

```
Option Explicit

Public MyRibbonUI As IRibbonUI
Public EnableButton1 As Boolean
Public EnableButton2 As Boolean
Public EnableButton3 As Boolean
Public EnableButton4 As Boolean


Public Sub OnRib_Load(ribbon As IRibbonUI)
'
' Code for onLoad callback. Ribbon control customUI
'
Set MyRibbonUI = ribbon
    EnableButton1 = True
    EnableButton2 = True
    EnableButton3 = True
    EnableButton4 = False

End Sub


Public Sub Button_GetEnabled(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef Enabled)
'
' Code for getEnabled callback. Ribbon control button
'
Select Case control.ID

    Case "Button1"
        Enabled = EnableButton1
    Case "Button2"
        Enabled = EnableButton2
    Case "Button3"
        Enabled = EnableButton3
    Case "Button4"
        Enabled = EnableButton4

End Select

End Sub

Public Sub Button1_onAction(control As IRibbonControl)
'
' Code for onAction callback. Ribbon control button
'
EnableButton1 = False
MyRibbonUI.InvalidateControl ("Button1")


End Sub
Public Sub Button2_onAction(control As IRibbonControl)
'
' Code for onAction callback. Ribbon control button
'
If EnableButton3 = False Then
    EnableButton3 = True
Else
    EnableButton3 = False
End If

MyRibbonUI.InvalidateControl ("Button3")

If EnableButton4 = False Then
    EnableButton4 = True
Else
    EnableButton4 = False
End If

MyRibbonUI.InvalidateControl ("Button4")

End Sub
Public Sub Button3_onAction(control As IRibbonControl)
'
' Code for onAction callback. Ribbon control button
'

End Sub
Public Sub Button4_onAction(control As IRibbonControl)
'
' Code for onAction callback. Ribbon control button
'
End Sub
```